# NSDateString Conversion

Tags: macos, nsdateformatter

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"W'th week of \n' MMMM YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
```

what i want is to output is

1st week of 
January 2013

2nd week of 
January 2013

3rd week of 
January 2013

4th week of 
January 2013

1st week of 
February 2013'

Comment: And what does it actually output?

Comment: the Nth week of the current month

Comment: Then it outputs exactly what you want. Now what's the problem?

Comment: that what i want but it said undefined variable date.

Comment: then you have a syntax error. Fix it.

Comment: do my line of codes correct . have you noticed any mistakes ..

Comment: ya i found one mistake in your code check my code one@ralphy Santos

Answer (score 1):

try this one it'l helps you ,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"W'th week of \n' MMMM YYYY"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

or

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"W'th week of \n' MMMM YYYY"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]); //here is your code went wrong
```